# Usings leaflet js set location from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I use the following code to open a popup

```
   var popup = L.popup();

 function onMapClick(e) {

 popup
.setLatLng(location)
.setContent(content)
.openOn(thisLeafletMap);
 thisLeafletMap.panTo(center);

 }
```

and can set location and content like this

```
 location = [51.5, -0.09];
 content = "I am a standalone popup.";
```

So the popup will display at those co-ordinates with I am a standalone popup. as the text on the popup.

Now, My links are constructed as

```
  a class="location" latlng="52.3395, -2.06612" content="my location" value="1">My location</a>
```

When the link is clicked I want it to update the location and content of the popup. So I use

```
  location = $(this).attr("latlng");
  content = $(this).attr("content");
```

The content will get updated. 
But I cannot get the location to set correctly.

I have tried

```
   location = "[" + $(this).attr("latlng") + "]";
```

and all variations I can think of.
If I alert the location it displays as I expect it.

I think this is a leaflet issue rather than a jquery issue.

What can I do?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating an array containing one string instead of an array containing 2 numbers. You could do something like this:

```
 <a class="location" lat="52.3395" lng="-2.06612" content="my location" value="1">My location</a>



   location = [$(this).attr("lat"), $(this).attr("lng")];
```